# Scala: sliding over a list without overlaps? (grouping pairs of consecutive elements in a list)

Tags: scala

Here is an example:

```
val list = List(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

We want to get:

```
val list = List((1,2),(3,4),(5,6))
```

Here is how I did. Is there a better way of doing it?

```
val eventElements = lines.zipWithIndex.filter { case (_, idx) => idx % 2 == 0 }.map { _._1 }
val oddElements = lines.zipWithIndex.filter { case (_, idx) => idx % 2 == 1 }.map { _._1 }
eventElements.zip(oddElements)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`grouped`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@grouped(size:Int):Iterator[Repr]):

```
list.grouped(2).toList
```